# With Delphi Xe2 and MySQL 5.1, how return UTF8 string from query?

Tags: mysql, delphi, utf-8

I'm developing a DataSnap server that make some query to db MySQL 5.1, tables are UTF8 and I saw correct latin, chinese, japanese, russian, greek, hindi text in tables.

When query the table I recieve "?????..." as response.

I have set names UTF8:

```
  SQLConnection1.Connected:= True;
  SQLConnection1.ExecuteDirect('set names utf8;');
```

then I do this:

```
  with DMMySQL.SQLDataSet1 do
  begin
    if Locate('COD_GOOGLE', LanguageValue, []) then
      Result:= UTF8Decode(FieldByName('DESCRIPTION').AsString); //
  end;
```

and Result always is "?????...." with or without `UTF8Decode`.

Where I'm wrong ?

TIA

Comment: Try to add ServerCharSet=UTF8 to connection parameters.

Comment: Adding ServerCharSet=UTF8 to connection params solved my problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you set the character set for a field/table, usually this is meant to ensure data are stored without lossy conversions, a proper collation is used, and some encondings may save space also. For example UTF-8 will store efficiently English strings (and most Western languages), and will be increasingly less efficient with other languages, compared to UTF-16.
Usually the driver - if set correctly - will translate the string from the database character set to the client application character set. You don't say what you're using to access MySQL (dbExpress? ODBC? Other?). Because Delphi Unicode strings are UTF-16, I guess the driver by default will tell MySQL to convert data to and from the UTF-16 enconding used by Delphi, regardless whatever encoding is used to store them inside MYSQL table.
If you tell MySQL to return data in UTF-8 and the driver or Delphi database code still store those data anyway into a UTF-16 string without converting it, you won't get the expected result.
What happens if you do not set a character set, or use a UTF-16 encoding?

Update: RAD Studio help says (ms-help://embarcadero.rs2010/rad/DbExpress_Data_Type_Mapping_for_Supported_Databases.html and http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/en/DbExpress_Data_Type_Mapping_for_Supported_Databases#MYSQL):

> dbExpress has the following MYSQL data type mappings:
>
> char  TDBXDataTypes.WideStringType if the server uses UTF-8; otherwise
>   TDBXDataTypes.AnsiStringType
>   varchar  TDBXDataTypes.WideStringType if the server uses UTF-8; otherwise TDBXDataTypes.AnsiStringType

Thereby if the server uses UTF-8 dbExpress should handle data in Delphi UTF-16, otherwise in an ANSI encoding. What kind of TField your application returns?

Comment: Thank you for replay. I'am using dbExpress - TSQLConnection and TSQLDataSet component. I have remmed the SQLConnection1.ExecuteDirect('set names utf8;') and changed SQLConnection1.Params.ServerCharSet to UTF16 but nothing has changed. Also I've set ServerCharSet to blank but allways result is ????... (I'm testing on greek; with german is ok).

Comment: For better information, data have been inserted using HeidiSQL 6.0 (written in Delphi). The source code of HeidiSQL show UTF8xxx functions (UTF8Encode, UTF8ToString....)

Comment: It seems that your data isn't corectly stored in the MySQL database, otherwise dbExpress woud handle all conversions for you. `UTF8Encode` and similar were primarily used before Delphi 2009 to circumvent the lack of Unicode support.

Comment: You can try to use `.AsBytes` and make sense of the TBytes using `TEncoding.UTF8.GetString`, `TEncoding.Unicode.GetString` and `TEncoding.Default.GetString`.

Comment: I've tried every suggestion. The last one is working. I've changed my code to Result:= TEncoding.UTF8.GetString(FieldByName('DESCRIPTION').AsBytes);

Comment: As I suspected, note that this is only a **workaround**. You should rather fix the encoding of the data in the database (if possible).

Answer (score 0):

Did you try `FieldByName('unicodefield').AsWideString`? IIRC dbExpress returns AnsiString with AsString.

Comment: Thank you. I've tried your suggestion but with a strange result. The proc was loading a greek frase (correctly loaded with the command TEncoding.UTF8.GetString(FieldByName('DESCRIPTION').AsBytes);). Otherwise, using Result:= FieldByName('DESCRIPTION').AsWideString is returned with chinese characters.