# Delphi, dbExpress and UTF8

Tags: mysql, delphi, utf-8, delphi-xe5, dbexpress

We've just upgraded our MySQL server from 5.0 to 5.1.

The remaining task is to finally sort out our Unicode support, which has been troubling us since Delphi 2010.  We are now using XE5.

The new database has been set up with default collation as **utf8-general-ci**.
The tables have been migrated with their original collation as **latin1-swedish-ci**.

At the moment all our applications read with `TSQLConnection.ServerCharSet = ""` as setting the read connections to **utf8** had unexpected results.

We write with connections set as `TSQLConnection.ServerCharSet = "utf8"`

I have now made a local copy of the new schema and have converted all the tables to **utf8-general-ci** - and this looks to have gone smoothly.

However, when I test on the new server it still is not smooth:

- Setting the read connection to **utf8** delivers results in some form of Kanji.
- Setting the read connection to **utf8-general-ci** or **""** reads correctly.
- Setting the write connection to **""** results in garbage when writing "£" or "€" chars
- Setting the write connection to **utf8** writes correctly

I suspect that the **utf8-general-ci** is not being recognised as an option by dbExpress so is being ignored

I also suspect that the SQLConnection.Locale setting may be an issue - currently this is set to 0000, but I've tried setting it to LOCALE_SYSTEM_DEFAULT (2048) with no success...

Is there any way we can avoid having 2 separate TSQLConnections for Read / Write routines?

**edit**

Based on suggestions by *Arioch 'The* I've ran a test with different string column types.  We've been using Text/Tinytext fields and that's where we've been seeing the problems.

The problem *does not* occur when using VarChar column types.

We'd like a suggestion that doesn't require us to use a third party driver/connection as that move does not fit with our current development strategy

Comment: did you tried MySQL DBX drivers from other vendors ?

Comment: No - at the moment only Embarcadero provided.

Comment: Try them even if only for "divide and conquer" bug binary searching

Comment: Devart MySQL drivers work with "Use Unicode" checked for both Read and Write...

Comment: google shows http://forums.mysql.com/read.php?49,81834,81834 AKA http://www.justsoftwaresolutions.co.uk/delphi/dbexpress_and_mysql_5.html - you would be able to fix any bugs if there exist, not being helpessly dependent on the vendor

Comment: That's quite an old article!  Before upgrading to MySQL 5.1 we'd found that dbExpress was supposed to support up to it (can't find the source now).  FireDAC has been introduced to provide support to modern version and if we're going to switch architecture then we'll probably go that way...

Comment: *That's quite an old article!* So what ? *if we're going to switch architecture* Switching architecture form db-express to db-express? what do you mean ? *dbExpress was supposed* dbExpress is only a framework to support any database, just like ODBC and ADO and SOAP and REST - those all are jsut frameworks. The support coems from certain drivers. You might take stock EMBT drivers and you might try different drivers and see if they would work. They might work or they might fail, but why not trying ? and with FLOSS drivers you might fix bugs yourselves. EMBT would never do, you know

Comment: Also you do not tell what do you read and what do you write, char, varchar, blob ? dunno how for MariaDB, for FirebirdSQL that made difference

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Final Comment from *Arioch 'The* lead me to find this question:

[With Delphi Xe2 and MySQL 5.1, how return UTF8 string from query?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8823942/with-delphi-xe2-and-mysql-5-1-how-return-utf8-string-from-query)

Which in turn lead to this Embarcadero page:

[dbExpress Data Type Mapping for Supported Databases](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/XE5/en/DbExpress_Data_Type_Mapping_for_Supported_Databases#MYSQL)

Wherein the answer is found:

text    TDBXDataTypes.AnsiStringType

i.e. Read `AsAnsiString` rather than `AsString`